# ImportError: No module named werkzeug.test [Installation on Windows]

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7, ckan

#### CKAN Version

CKan 2.5.2

```
git clone https://github.com/ckan/ckan.git
git checkout tags/ckan-2.5.2
```

I follow https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/How-to-Install-CKAN-2.5.2-on-Windows-7 
From the beginning to the step "Create database tables"
    (ckan2.5.2env) D:\src\ckan>paster db init -c development.ini

Error Occurs:

```
  File "d:\users\administrator.user1-pc\envs\ckan2.5.2env\lib\site-packages\pkg_
resources\__init__.py", line 2303, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "d:\users\administrator.user1-pc\envs\ckan2.5.2env\lib\site-packages\pkg_
resources\__init__.py", line 2309, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "D:\src\ckan\ckan\config\middleware\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from werkzeug.test import create_environ, run_wsgi_app
```

> ImportError: No module named werkzeug.test

After running >easy_install werkzeug
The error changed to :

> ImportError: No module named flask

After running >easy_install flask
The error changed to :

> ImportError: No module name config
>   and this cannot be resolved.

Referening to line #6 on ..\ckan\config\middleware__init__.py
It imports the following

```
import webob from werkzeug.test import create_environ, run_wsgi_app
from ckan.config.environment import load_environment from
ckan.config.middleware.flask_app import make_flask_stack from
ckan.config.middleware.pylons_app import make_pylons_stack
```

---

Try to correct requiremnets.txt

```
File"D:\ckan\config\middleware\flask_app.py", line 6, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name config
(ckan2.5.2env) D:\src\ckan>pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting bleach==1.4.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))  Using cached bleach-1.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: bleach  Found existing installation: bleach 2.0.0    Uninstalling bleach-2.0.0:      
Successfully uninstalled bleach-2.0.0Successfully installed bleach-1.4.2(ckan2.5.2env) 
D:\src\ckan>paster db init -c development.ini
File"d:\ckan2.5.2env\lib\site-packages\bleach\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>    from html5lib.sanitizer import HTMLSanitizer
ImportError: No module named sanitizer
(ckan2.5.2env) D:\src\ckan>pip install --upgrade bleach
Successfully uninstalled bleach-1.4.2Successfully installed bleach-2.0.0
(ckan2.5.2env) D:\src\ckan>paster db init -c development.ini
File"D:\ckan\config\middleware\flask_app.py", line 6, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name config
```

---

Try to change from ckan2.5.2 to 2.5.4

The **init**.py seems to be fixed.
Therefore, a further Locale problem is shown

(ckan2.5.4env) d:\src\ckan>paster --plugin=ckan user list -c development.ini

> ```
> import i18n
> File "d:\ckan2.5.4env\lib\site-packages\ckan-2.6.1-py2.7.egg\ckan\lib\i18n.py",
> ```
>
> line 46, in 
>       from babel.core import (LOCALE_ALIASES,
>       ImportError: cannot import name get_locale_identifier

i18n.py, line 46,
from babel import Locale
from babel.core import (LOCALE_ALIASES, get_locale_identifier, UnknownLocaleError)

Comment: You don't mention the rest of the install steps you followed. e.g.`pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: I follow https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/How-to-Install-CKAN-2.5.2-on-Windows-7 
From the beginning to the step "Create database tables"
(ckan) C:\src\ckan>paster db init -c development.ini

Then, the ImportError is recieved

Answer (score 1):

`ImportError` suggests you didn't complete this step `pip install -r requirements.txt` successfully. Try enabling your virtualenv and doing that step again, and make sure it completes successfully.

Please also ensure you're using the latest patch release. 2.5.2 has been superceded by 2.5.4 and you should always use one of the latest. This will likely fix for the sanitizer/bleach/html5 versioning problem.

Comment: Seems to have a bit progress. A different error 
"No module named sanitizer" have been shown.

Comment: For the sanitizer error, Google found this: https://github.com/stephenmcd/cartridge/issues/304 
For the 'config' error, Google found this: https://lists.okfn.org/pipermail/ckan-dev/2016-September/010295.html

Comment: BTW you should use CKAN 2.5.4 now, rather than 2.5.2 to get patches (see your git checkout). These may help with the dependencies - there was a muddle with bleach and html5 at some point that may have been fixed in these patches. Or simply try this one: `pip install html5lib==0.9999999`

Comment: Try to change from ckan2.5.2 to 2.5.4
The __init__.py seems to be fixed.
i18n.py, line 46, from babel import Locale from babel.core import (LOCALE_ALIASES, get_locale_identifier, UnknownLocaleError) has been thrown. Wondering how far is the destination.

Comment: I suspect this is a Windows thing. Not something I can help with.

Comment: You already help a lot. Thank you. I will try to install ubuntu on VM.